# Hide constructor using module in Haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor, module, abstract

I have defined a `data Teorema` in NDOblig.hs and I need to hide the constructors to make it an abstrac type.

I know how to do it using a different .hs and importing the module NDOblig like this on Main.hs:

```
module Main where

import NDOblig
```

But is there any way of making it in the same .hs?

Here is part of my code:

```
module NDOblig(Var, Form(L,Bot,Impl, And, Or, Not), Teorema, concl, hips, hip, implI, implE, botE, noI, noE, oIi, oId, oE, yI, yEi, yEd) where

--2 Fórmulas
type Var = String
data Form = L Var | Bot | Impl Form Form | And Form Form | Or Form Form | Not Form
    deriving (Show, Eq)

--3 Teoremas
data Teorema = H Form | ImplI Form Teorema | ImplE Teorema Teorema | BotE Form Teorema | Raa Form Teorema
 | NoI Form Teorema  | NoE Teorema Teorema | OIi Form Teorema | OId Form Teorema | OE Teorema Teorema Teorema
 | YI Teorema Teorema | YEi Teorema | YEd Teorema
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope—the only way to hide constructors is to refuse to export them, so you need at least one module boundary to refuse to export them over!

Comment: From a practical standpoint, you could just have a constructor name that is so long you would get too tired trying to type it in then give up and use the smart constructor...